# Gridster grid arranging widgets for better packing

Tags: gridster

I am using gridster for building a dashboard, dashboard will support adding, removing, moving & resizing of widgets. Gridster does everything I want & is quite a comprehensive framework.
However I wonder if I can achieve better packing(less empty spaces) of widgets specially when you move them around. 
In this gridster demo
http://gridster.net/ , when you move a widget the whole grid is NOT rearrange for better packing.
However something like freewall - http://vnjs.net/www/project/freewall/ does a full grid rearrange and ends up with much better utilization of space.

Gridster does support auto position in addWidget() which works nicely.How can I achieve better packing with gridster when resized, moved or delete of widgets?

Answer (score 0):

Repositioning widgets after remove a widget

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36358231/how-to-position-the-jquery-gridster-after-remove-a-widget
```